# XGBoost - predict not exported in namespace

Tags: r, xgboost, mlr

I am trying to tune an xgboost model with a multiclass dependent variable in R. I am using MLR to do this, however I run into an error where xgboost doesn't have predict within its namespace - which I assume MLR wants to use. I have had a look online and see that other people have encountered similar issues. However, I can't entirely understand the answers that have been provided (e.g. https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/935), when I try to implement them the issue persists. My code is as follows:

```
# Tune parameters
#create tasks
train$result <- as.factor(train$result)  # Needs to be a factor variable for makeClass to work
test$result <- as.factor(test$result)
traintask <- makeClassifTask(data = train,target = "result")
testtask <- makeClassifTask(data = test,target = "result")

lrn <- makeLearner("classif.xgboost",predict.type = "response")

# Set learner value and number of rounds etc.
lrn$par.vals <- list(
 objective = "multi:softprob",  # return class with maximum probability,
 num_class = 3,  # There are three outcome categories
 eval_metric="merror",
 nrounds=100L,
  eta=0.1
)

# Set parameters to be tuned
params <- makeParamSet(
 makeDiscreteParam("booster",values = c("gbtree","gblinear")),
 makeIntegerParam("max_depth",lower = 3L,upper = 10L),
 makeNumericParam("min_child_weight",lower = 1L,upper = 10L),
 makeNumericParam("subsample",lower = 0.5,upper = 1),
 makeNumericParam("colsample_bytree",lower = 0.5,upper = 1)
)

# Set resampling strategy
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("CV",stratify = T,iters=5L)

# search strategy
ctrl <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 10L)
#parallelStartSocket(cpus = detectCores())  # Enable parallel processing

 mytune <- tuneParams(learner = lrn
                 ,task = traintask
                 ,resampling = rdesc
                 ,measures = acc
                 ,par.set = params
                 ,control = ctrl
                 ,show.info = T)
```

The specific error I get is:
`Error: 'predict' is not an exported object from 'namespace:xgboost'`

My package versions are:

```
packageVersion("xgboost")
[1] ‘0.6.4’

packageVersion("mlr")
[1] ‘2.8’
```

Would anyone know what I should do here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try upgrading mlr. The xgboost learner regularly needs to be adapted to changes in their code base.

Comment: Hi. I upgraded to the development version and it is now working. I probably should have checked that before posting. Thanks for your help!